# Load JQuery cycle2 on loaded Ajax content

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to initiate JQuery cycle on external HTML content loaded in with Ajax, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$(".container").load("step2.html", function() {
                $.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.cycle-slideshow';
});
```

the html is as follows:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow second-prize-slider" data-cycle-manual-speed="2000" data-cycle-slides="p" data-cycle-timeout=5000 >
                                         <p>Jetzt<br />mitmachen & <br />gewinnen</span></p>   
                                         <p >Täglich<br>mitspielen & <br> Gewinnchance<br> steigern!</p> 
                                    </div>
```

Comment: using that kind of initialization only works on elements that exist at dom ready. you'll have to initialize it manually in the .load callback.

Comment: Like the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the `cycle` initializer manually in your callback:

```
$(".container").load("step2.html", function() {
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle();
});
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works only if you add `$` symbol in a `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` and make your functions global to call them inside you ajax call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  window.script_cycle = function() {
     $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle();
   }
// the function below if you want to add or change some attributes to your cycle
  window.cycle_attr = function() {
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx: 'fade', 
    speed: 1500,
    });
   }
});
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'http://yoururl.com',
data: { param : value }, // if youre using http://yoururl.com?param=value
success: function(data){
  script_cycle(); // global function from previous document.ready to be called here
} 
   });
// if youre using load same procedure here
$(".container").load("step2.html", function() {
    script_cycle();
   });
});
```

Seems to be a bug from the plugin the need for $ in the document ready, but using this procedure worked for me, Cheers!.

Comment: I forgot, you may want to add <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js?ver=2.0.6" type="text/javascript"></script> just above the code i posted for proper functioning

Comment: Also for loading content of your url in the $.ajax function you may wanna add $('.container').html($(data).html()); after success: function(data){  just above script_cycle();